# Post comment via API to ADO Boards Work Item with hyperlink

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create or update a work item in ADO via the API.

I'd like to create a hyperlink in the comments section. I'm using the system.history field in ADO and so far I have tried the following in my payload for the field:

- URL encoding (`system.history=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`) Displays - `https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`
- Markup (`system.history=[google](https://google.com)`) Displays - `[google](https://google.com)`
- plain text (`system.history=https://google.com`) Displays - `https://google.com`
- HTML (`system.history=<div><a href="https://google.com">google</a></div>`) Displays nothing

This comment field seems to support full HTML capabilities from the work item UI, can it do the same via API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

Request body:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.History",
        "value": "<div>Link: <a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/\">https://stackoverflow.com/</a></div>"
    }
]
```

Test in postman:

[image]

Test result:

[image]